# I need comma in between figures in php

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal-point

I don't know how to display my numbers to have commas and a decimal point in php..

I want 12345.90 to be displayed as 12,345.90

thanks in advance

Comment: Try with number_format function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: the page is in Russia I think

Comment: Updated my comment. You can change PHP website language with the dropdown. However someone answered you below, but make sure to read the docs for personal knowledge ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add commas to numbers in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582562/how-can-i-add-commas-to-numbers-in-php)

Comment: FWIW, such a comma is commonly called a "thousands separator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function. It will solve your problem.

Try this:

```
echo number_format(12345.90, 2, '.', ','); // Prints 12,345.90
```