# How can I add commas separator to numbers (thousands, hundred thousand, million, billion) in PHP

Tags: php, number-formatting

I would like to add comas separator when the value goes up to hundred thousand, million, billion.

How can do that ?

My references in http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

My current code can add commas on thousand separator.

```
<?php
  $output = "1000000"; 
  if($output == "NULL"){
    echo "0";
  } else {
    $output;
    $new = number_format($output, 2, '.', ',');
    if($new == "0.00"){
      echo "0";
    } else {
      echo $new;
    }
  }
?>
```

Output :

```
1000 into 1,000.00
```

The problem comes when the value reach 1 million. It shows like this.

```
100000,000.00
```

It doesnt add the commas between hundred thousands and million.

I want my final value look like this.

```
1,000,000.00
```

Appreciate pros here can help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/RgpL3 Seems to behave for me, do you have any special regional/country localisation settings in your php.ini config?

Comment: works fine for me, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4a1d3fbdd59c1ea1c4f0be5cfc1d50d5f28daded The issue you have is you are not adding any space or new line between the echos.

Comment: I would sack, all that `null` and `0.00` crap and just use empty.

Comment: Whats this? `echo $output = "1000000";`  That and then no `"\n" after you echo, is jamming your output together and making  `echo "1000"` and `echo "1,000.00"` look like something it is not.  I doubt your output is what you say, what is the initial value of `$output`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add commas to numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582562/how-can-i-add-commas-to-numbers-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you confusing yourself because of this mistake.

```
echo $output = "1000000";
```

Set it to `"1000000"` then echo it, then your code executes and it all gets jammed together.

For an example:

```
$output = 1000;//initial value

echo $output = "1000000"; //initial value is overwritten then echoed
if($output == "NULL"){
  echo "0";
} else {
  $output;
  $new = number_format($output, 2, '.', ',');
  if($new == "0.00"){
    echo "0";
  } else {
    echo $new;
  }
}
```

outputs:

10000001,000,000.00

This is your code unmodified.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e3fb6e3d34c3ef70b09bcd63081c0ca8bc357c3)

Now if you remove that echo

```
$output = "1000000";
```

You will see

```
1,000,000.00
```

[Sandbox2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56ff4be0a206061c6890433a7ae0caf867fde017)

Now Note I did not modify your code except to remove that first echo.  Now if you really want to do this `echo $output = "1000000";` which I would not really suggest as it's ugly. you could put some kind of separation after it.

```
echo $output = "1000000";  
echo PHP_EOL.'---------------'.PHP_EOL;
```

Then you get

```
1000000
---------------
1,000,000.00
```

By default echo doesn't create a new line.

Make sense,