# how to output INT values with proper commas from a mysql table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, math

people. I have Ajax/Jquery to output values from a MySQL table, but I am receiving the values with no commas. Instead of 10,000, I receive 10000.
What can I do to fix this?

This is one of the Ajax/Jquery calls code:

```js
$('#red').on('click', function() {
  var colorId = $(this).attr("id");

  $.ajax({
    "url": "tables.php",
    "data": {
      "color": colorId
    },
    success: function(response) {
      response = Number(response);
      $("#redr").text(response);
      console.log(response);
```

This will pass the variable and output the votes of the "red" color in my MySQL table, which columns are: city, color, votes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582562/how-can-i-add-commas-to-numbers-in-php

Comment: You can use mySQL's format function to return formatted string for your votes: FORMAT(votes, 2)